# GolangのUnMarshalでjsonをStructに変換した後、Marshalでjsonに変換した場合、配列の部分がオブジェクトになってしまうので配列を維持したい

Tags: go

#### やりたいこと

- jsonで`{"color":"red","mrkdwn_in":["text"]}`をUnMarshalで構造体に変換
- colorをred→blueに変更
- 変更された構造体をMarshalでjsonに変更
- 元々の`"mrkdwn_in":["text"]`がうまく維持されない

  - `"mrkdwn_in":[{"text":""}]`や`"mrkdwn_in":""`になってしまう。
- mrkdwn_inの部分は元々の状態を維持したいです。

#### コード

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Color        string       `json:"color"`
    MrkdwnIn     []MrkdwnIn   `json:"mrkdwn_in"`
}

type MrkdwnIn struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData1 := "{\"color\":\"red\",\"mrkdwn_in\":[\"text\"]}"
    var body TestStruct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData1), &body)
    body.Color = "blue"
    var jsonData2 []byte
    jsonData2, _ = json.Marshal(body)

    jsonDataText := string(jsonData2)
    fmt.Println(jsonDataText)
}
```

#### 上記コードの実行結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `TestStruct` 型や `Mrkdwnln` 型の宣言内容を見ますと、`jsonData1` は `\`{"color":"red","mrkdwn_in":[{"text":"text"}]}\`` とするのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

これで解決しました。

```
MrkdwnIn     []MrkdwnIn   `json:"mrkdwn_in"`
```

↓

```
MrkdwnIn     []string     `json:"mrkdwn_in"`
```